# Unable to create a Secret Using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-secrets

I am trying to follow steps from
ref URL: [Secrets-Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) to create a Secret Using kubectl,
I was able to create files

1. username.txt
2. password.txt

which show under pwd

```
[root@1161 cdp]# ls
password.txt  username.txt
```

and now when I try to execute the next statement which is

```
kubectl create secret generic db-user-pass --from-file=./username.txt --from-file=./password.txt
```

I get following error:

```
error: Missing or incomplete configuration info.  Please point to an existing, complete config file:
 1. Via the command-line flag --kubeconfig
 2. Via the KUBECONFIG environment variable
 3. In your home directory as ~/.kube/config

 To view or setup config directly use the 'config' command.
```

Note: I'm running the statement behind corporate proxy, Please advise on how to proceed further

> This is on centos 7

```
kubectl version --client
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.2",
GitCommit:"52c56ce7a8272c798dbc29846288d7cd9fbae032", GitTreeState:"clean",
BuildDate:"2020-04-16T11:56:40Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Best Regards,
MK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a config file manually and then set KUBECONFIG env by doing

```
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config
```

### My_Config file

apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    api-version: v1
    server: "my-server"
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
  name: default-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default-cluster
    namespace: "my-namespace"
    user: default-user
  name: default-context
current-context: default-context
kind: Config
users:
- name: default-user
  user:
    token: "my-token"

```
secret/my-secret created
```

Thanks all for your support, Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have setup the Kubectl config credentials correctly.

You can fetch the credentials like below:

For google:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster name> --zone <zone> --project <project id>
```

For AWS:

```
aws eks --region region update-kubeconfig --name cluster_name
kubectl get pods --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config
```

Comment: Thanks Vishnu, I believe that I have to create a config file as I get no such file or directory error
please advise on how to get a config file created so as to run kubectl create secret command

Comment: When you run the above commands it will automatically create the config file. Currently where you are running this ? Is it in AWS EKS cluster or Google cloud GKE? or are you running it locally? like minikube?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the secret files one at a time. For example this works for me

```
kubectl.exe create secret generic server-secrets --from-file=sachaserver-secrets-properties
```

Comment: Hi Sacha, Still the same 
I tried [root@1161 cdp]# kubectl create secret generic db-user --from-file=./username.txt
error: Missing or incomplete configuration info.  Please point to an existing, complete config file:

Answer (score 0):

Can you please do `kubectl config current-context`? Wondering if you already authenticated on the right cluster or not. If not you have to option whether directly passing the file kubeconfig each time you call the command or set it one time.

Comment: Thanks for your response,
[mk@1161 kubectl_lab]$ kubectl config current-context
error: current-context is not set

How to set kubeconfig one time? please advise

Comment: First you can try to look at all of your context, by using `kubectl config view` https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-context-and-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the KUBECONFIG env manually.

```
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```

Comment: Thanks Harika, What configuration am I setting here?
[mk@1161 /]$ cd etc/kubernetes/
[mk@inblr1161 kubernetes]$ ls
addons

I believe that I have to create an admin.conf file but I'm not sure what would I fill in?
please advise

Comment: 1.How did you install kubernetes ? yum install ?

Comment: Afaik Any kubernetes platform comes with kubectl installed properly.
I believe no kubectl commands will be running for you, not only creating secrets.
Please check this link in case installed kubeadm  manually and setting the kubernetes env (https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#more-information)
_To make kubectl work for your non-root user, run these commands, which are also part of the kubeadm init output:_

Comment: Hi Harika,
I was able to set KUBECONFIG env manually 
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config
and created config file manually


config-file
---
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    api-version: v1
    server: "my-server"
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
  name: default-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default-cluster
    namespace: "my-namespace"
    user: default-user
  name: default-context
current-context: default-context
kind: Config
users:
- name: default-user
  user:
    token: "my-token"